# SELECT list not showing in IE8 due to "height : 75%" CSS

Tags: html, css, select, internet-explorer-8

I have a webapp that displays a list of names as options in a SELECT block:

```
<select name="names" .... >
    <option value="Lee">
    <option value="Jamie">
    <option value="Alex">
</select>
```

I am then applying some CSS to the SELECT block to size it and what not:

```
width : 100%
height : 75%
```

This works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but not IE8.  In IE8 the SELECT block doesn't show at all, though it is of course included in the source.  I have tracked it down using the IE8 developer tools to the height attribute being the problem.  If I remove it in the dev tools, the box appears as I would like it.  However, if I take the height attribute completely out, it doesn't appear as I would like in Firefox or Chrome.

Is there anyway I can add a condition to the CSS to say that if the browser is IE to not add the height?  Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your comments.  I just removed the height attribute and added a size attribute to the select box so that it always shows only 35 options before scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional comments.

```
<!--[if IE 8]> 
  <link href="/css/ie_8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<![endif]-->
```

In the above instance, you are linking to a specific IE8 stylesheet.  This would go in the head of the doc.

You could also just add the style to the page in question.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
   <style type="text/css">
       .list{height:100%;}
   </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to size it against? The `75%` would be "75% of the height of the parent element".

IE doesn't like height to be measured in percent when it doesn't have a fixed height for the parent element. If you give the parent element a fixed height, it should work. But I guess that might break other aspects of your layout.

Depending on the context, you might be able to acheive the effect you're after by using `em` units instead of percent.

For example, if the container is a single line, you could acheive the same thing by using `0.75em` instead of `75%`. (not that this would be particularly useful, as it would obscure parts of the select box, but you get the idea)